# sql cannot operate correctly in Redshift

Tags: jdbc, mybatis, amazon-redshift

I want to run sql like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable AS SELECT * FROM redshift_table WHERE date > #{date};
```

I can run this sql in command line in Redshift, but if I run it in my program, it doesn't work correctly. When I change `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE` it works correctly.

I am using mybatis as OR mapper and driver is:

- org.postgresql.Driver
- org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the #date is an actual date in your actual query.

Having said that, there is not reason this command doesnt work, its as per the syntax listed here,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html

Have you tried posting it on AWS Redshift forums, generally they are quite responsive. Please update this thread too if you find something, this is quite an interesting issue, thanks!